# Java servlet - Retrieve text and value from an HTML select multiple

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an HTML select box in my JSP page that allows multiple selections.

```
<form action="resources" method="post" >
    <select name="frmSelectedResources" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Bill</option>
        <option value="3">Kathy</option>
        <option value="18">Mike</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In my Java servlet I can get the values of the select resources with:

```
String[] assignedResources = request.getParameterValues("frmSelectedResources");
```

Which give me a string array of 1,3,18. But how can I retrieve the text for each of these values?

I need to get back something like this: (1,Bill), (3, Kathy), (18, Mike)

What I’m trying to do is rebuild the Selected Resource list when I’m doing forms validation and the user made a data entry error elsewhere on the form.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: How did your JSP know that the value 1 should be associated with "Bill"? Can't you use the same code on the server side to "lookup" the label for value 1?

Comment: The select list is built from a database table.  I was hoping to avoid making a request back to the database to get the names associated with the Resource values from the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't receive it from request parameter (unless you explicitly set it), Browser only sends the value of select item not the label, it uses label just to display

Have a map that resolves label from value received

Comment: Since my Resource list is originally built from a database table, how can I create a map to resolve the text labels for each received value?  My Resource table has approximately 100 records in it.

Comment: if it is not roo frequent you could directly query database based on value received from request parameter, if its too frequent cache it in map

Comment: I used a HashMap to lookup the Display Name for the Resource IDs returned by the getParameterValues.  I was then able to rebuild my Select box if a validation error occurred.

Answer (score 4):

Create some character separated key, While filling up SELECT options.

```
<form action="resources" method="post" >
    <select name="frmSelectedResources" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1:Bill">Bill</option>
        <option value="3:Kathy">Kathy</option>
        <option value="18:Mike">Mike</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The Use it

```
String[] assignedResources = request.getParameterValues("frmSelectedResources");
if (assignedResources != null) {
    for(String item: assignedResources){
        String keyValue[]= item.split(":");
        out.println("Key: " + keyValue[0]);
        out.println("Value: " + keyValue[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get value only. If you want text, One of the way may be,  change value to something like `"1-Bill"` etc., and parse it inside servlet.